# Convert unicode like u'\xhh' to string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am using python2 module pytaglib to edit mp3 tags. One mp3's ARTIST is

```
u'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'
```

When I print above unicode, it raise an error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xc3' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

After error I add line 3-5 below

```
import taglib
song = taglib.File("D:/song.mp3")
for i in song.tags.iteritems():
    print i
print
for k,v in song.tags.iteritems():
    print k+":",
    print v[0]
```

It displays

```
(u'ALBUM', [u'Lemon'])
(u'TITLE', [u'Lemon'])
(u'ARTIST', [u'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'])
(u'ENCODING', [u'Lavf57.71.100'])
(u'ALBUMARTIST', [u'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'])
(u'TRACKNUMBER', [u'1'])

ALBUM: Lemon
TITLE: Lemon
ARTIST: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/mp3tag.py", line 8, in <module>
    print v[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xc3' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Then I tried the code below

```
>print '\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'
米津玄師
```

I have to print the unicode this way

```
s = u'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'
print eval('"'+repr(s)[2:-1]+'"')
```

Is there a better way to convert `u'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'` to `'\xc3\xd7\xbd\xf2\xd0\xfe\x8e\x9f'`?

Comment: @pynexj: Do you know how to do it in py3?

Comment: see this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315872/how-to-convert-string-containing-unicode-escape-u-to-utf-8-string

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added some code.